# Animations in AngularJS 1.2 - How To

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I tried to use animations within my app but unfortunately to no avail. I checked lots of examples, [blog](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html), downloaded [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) etc etc.

I injected animation module, tried basic examples, tried following [tutorials](http://www.nganimate.org) for instance, but it seems I miss something every time.

Can someone please provide exact instructions for AngularJS  v1.2 animations to work, with injections, inclusions and everything you need to do to get them working? Maybe a step-by-step instructions on how you usually do your animations.

A basic fadein/fadeout example on ng-show/hide would suffice.

Thank you very much

Comment: You might be interested in this demo app: http://dfsq.github.io/ngView-animation-effects/app.

Comment: this is especially for ngView? I'm interested in show/hide animations for divs with ng-show directive on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Reference angular-animate.js
- Add ngAnimate as a dependent module:

  ```
  myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
  ```
- Add a div to your view with the `ng-show` directive and for example the two classes 'fadein' and 'fadeout':

  ```
  <div class="fadein fadeout" ng-show="show">I am the div.</div>
  ```
- Add the classes to your css. In 1.2 ngAnimate is class-based and you need to add certain suffixes to your classes based on a certain naming convention. A good source of information regarding this can be found [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#how-to-make-animations-in-angularjs).

  Example:

  ```
  /* Fade in ngShow */
  .fadein.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;   
    display: block !important;     
    opacity: 0;
  }

  .fadein.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
  }


  /* Fade out ngShow */
  .fadeout.ng-hide-add {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    transition: 1s;     
    display: block !important;    
    opacity: 1;
  }

  .fadeout.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  ```
- Add logic to change the expression that is provided to the `ng-show` directive and the div should fade in and out.

  A working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/lq4LmUq5mrbJBGMMEyh9?p=preview

Comment: woooah, this finally works! I probably used almost the same scenario more than once, but it never worked. Thank you